# Alguna solucion para JASPERSOFT?, Error con com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: mysql, jaspersoft

[image: Ya le cambie el tipo de conector pero me sigue apareciendo el mismo error]
Ya le cambie el tipo de conector pero me sigue apareciendo el mismo error

Comment: No está instalado el JAR con el driver. Cambiar el tipo no cambia el que no esté instalado